# Android - CheckBox blocks onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I register the context menu for my list:

```
this.registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

and implement the required method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    menu.setHeaderTitle("title");

    String[] rssContextMenuItems = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
    for (int i = 0; i < rssContextMenuItems.length; i++)
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, rssContextMenuItems[i]);
}
```

The problem is that I have got a custom view in the list, containing a checkbox.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- some elements -->

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/my_id"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <!-- some more -->

</LinearLayout>
```

I have already tried the `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` trick, but when I long press the checkbox it still does not trigger the `onCreateContextMenu` method.

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: What I did is to create a TextView for the text of the checkbox. I don't put a text value to the CheckBox widget. So I created a TextView beside it.